# UIImageView changes their position when the UITableViewCell is selected

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uitableview

I have an `UIImageView` inside of a `UITableViewCell`, and when I select the `cell` the `imageView` changes their position like this:

Before tapping:
[image: Before tapping]

After tapping:
[image: After tapping]

Is this a bug with *iOS* or something I've done wrong?

Edit: `didSelectRowAt` code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let list = indexPath.section == 0 ? subscribed****s : other****s
    if (list == subscribed****s) {
        // Removed line that was setting a variable inside a class
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueNameRemoved", sender: self)
    } else {
        if (array.contains(removedValue)) {
            // Removed line that was setting a variable inside a class
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueNameRemoved", sender: self)
        } else {
            // TODO
            // This is where the code ended and the image position was changed
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show some of your code please. What would be specifically helpful is what you have in the `UITableViewDelegate` method: `didSelectRowAt`

Comment: @Pierce OP edited with that method

Comment: How are you adding the imageView to the tableViewCell? Is it simply an accessoryView?

Comment: @KawinP. the image view was added to the cell via the storyboard.

Comment: Did you add Constraints to that uiimageview?

Comment: @VandanPatel yes, the image view has constraints.

Comment: @Jordan Osterberg have you taken any view on your cell?

Comment: @TusharSharma what do you mean? I only have my `UILabel` and `UIImageView` inside of my cell.

Comment: @Jordan Osterberg I mean add a uiview on your cell then place all the IBoutlet you want on that view and apply your constraints for every outlet again including uiview correctly it will not give you any such weird issue..

Answer (score 0):

Currently I ran into this problem. And I found out my reason. Maybe is also your reason.

> Don't call your imageView "imageView".
>
> Call it another.

Because UITableViewCell has its own imageView.